# Unable to load my application into IFRAME

Tags: html, spring, iframe, spring-security, https

I'm unable to load my test https(with self signed certificate) site into iframe from 127.0.0.1/localhost/example.com

In my Java Spring application I have added following line:

```
.headers().frameOptions().disable().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "ALLOW-FROM example.com"))
```

but still unable to load my application https://127.0.0.1:8443 into IFRAME

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://127.0.0.1:8443"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to allow loading of my application into iframe ?

Comment: Refer the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28649205/1533666 and my answer to understand the X-FRAME-OPTIONS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `ALLOW-FROM` but ALLOW-FROM is not supported in Chrome or Safari.

Refer: [X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM in firefox and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658435/x-frame-options-allow-from-in-firefox-and-chrome)

#### How to disable ?

[How to disable 'X-Frame-Options' response header in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647136/how-to-disable-x-frame-options-response-header-in-spring-security)

#### What is X-FRAME-OPTIONS?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

[How to deny site access from an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397267/how-to-deny-site-access-from-an-iframe)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx

Comment: .headers().frameOptions().disable(); Finally I got it working. Thanks a lot !!